# What's the function of this と

Tags: grammar

これを青いのと取り替えてください。
I can't figure how this と (〜のと) 
works here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「これ**を**青{あお}いの**と**取{と}り替{か}えてください。」

First of all, 「青いの」 means "a blue one".

> 「A + **を** + B + **と or に** + 取り替える」

means:

> "to exchange A for B"

So, in this case, the と or に functions as the "for" in the English equivalent.  You have no choice but to use it to make it grammatical.

> "Please exchange this for a blue one."